# How to register assembly using custom action in WIX toolset

Tags: custom-action, wix3, regasm

My Wix toolset installer installs many files, but only one of these I would like to register for `COM interop`.  I have tried the heat automatic registration but can't get it to work, so am falling back to what I used to do in `installshield` which is run a custom action at the end of installation to register using `regasm`.
This is failing for reasons I don't understand.

My `Product.wxs` file registers the action as follows:

```
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="RegisterAddIn" After="InstallFiles">NOT REMOVE</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Then creates the action here:

```
  <Fragment>
    <CustomAction Id ="RegisterAddIn" Directory ="INSTALLFOLDER" Execute="immediate" ExeCommand="[WindowsFolder]Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm /codebase /tlb &quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]Aeolus.Excel.Addin.dll&quot;" Return ="check"/>
  </Fragment>
```

On running this installer I get the error

> "A program run as part of setup did not finish as expected."

Extract from the msiexec log doesn't shown below.

```
CustomAction RegisterAddIn returned actual error code 100 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
MSI (s) (54:38) [12:40:54:765]: Note: 1: 1722 2: RegisterAddIn 3: C:\Program Files (x86)\Aeolus\ 4: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm /codebase /tlb "C:\Program Files (x86)\Aeolus\Aeolus.Excel.Addin.dll" 
MSI (s) (54:38) [12:40:54:765]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (54:38) [12:40:54:765]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1722 
Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action RegisterAddIn, location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Aeolus\, command: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm /codebase /tlb "C:\Program Files (x86)\Aeolus\Aeolus.Excel.Addin.dll" 
MSI (s) (54:38) [12:40:56:746]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (54:38) [12:40:56:746]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1709 
MSI (s) (54:38) [12:40:56:746]: Product: Aeolus -- Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.  Action RegisterAddIn, location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Aeolus\, command: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm /codebase /tlb "C:\Program Files (x86)\Aeolus\Aeolus.Excel.Addin.dll"
```

Editing the `.msi` file with `Orca`, I have this entry in the table which looks correct to me:

```
[WindowsFolder]Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm /codebase /tlb "[INSTALLFOLDER]Aeolus.Excel.Addin.dll"
```

If I remove these custom actions, run my installer, then run this in a command prompt (run as administrator):

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm  /codebase /tlb  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Aeolus\Aeolus.Excel.Addin.dll"
```

It registers fine.  if not run as administrator it fails of course.  Can I assume any custom actions will be run as administrator?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has similar issues, I managed to fix it.  It turned out to be a permission issue.  I was assuming that the installer and all custom actions ran as administrator but actually you have to tell it to run at that level of permission.

So I needed to make 3 fixes.
1. Request elevated permission in package definintion:

```
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" InstallPrivileges="elevated" AdminImage="yes"/>
```

2. Set "Execute" to "deferred" and "Impersonate" to "no" in custom action definition:

```
<CustomAction Id ="RegisterAddIn" Directory ="INSTALLFOLDER" Execute="deferred" ExeCommand="[WindowsFolder]Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm /codebase /tlb &quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]Aeolus.Excel.Addin.dll&quot;" Return ="check" Impersonate="no"/>
```

Then it all runs as expected.